# Interpretation of the join of two stabilizer subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be the group acting on two sets $X, Y$.
Let $G_x$ and $G_y$ be stabilizer subgroups of some elements $x \in X, y \in Y$.
It is easy to see that $G_x \cap G_y = G_{(x,y)}$, when we combine two actions in a standard way to get a $G$-action on $X \times Y$.

I'm interested if there is a similar "natural" interpretation for the [join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_of_subgroups) of $G_x$ and $G_y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f\colon G\rightarrow X$ be the map $f(g)=gx$, and $h\colon
G\rightarrow Y$ the map $h(g)=gy$.  Let $Z=X\coprod_{x=y} Y$ be the
push-out or colimit of the diagram made out of $f$ and $h$ in the
category of $G$-sets. Let $i\colon X\rightarrow Z$ and $j\colon
Y\rightarrow Z$ be the maps that come along with $Z$. Then
$i(x)=j(y)$, and the stabilizer of this point $z=i(x)=j(y)$ of $Z$ is
the join of $G_x$ and $G_y$ in $G$.